# Implementing generic pagination in Nest.JS and TypeORM (DRY, testable)

Tags: pagination, nestjs, typeorm

I've noticed that the pagination code tends to repeat itself from entity to entity, and that it should be abstracted out, i.e. **limiting and skipping documents does not care what type of underlying document we are on**, so there's no need to write the same code for many different entities.

What is the best way to generalize pagination on the TypeORM repositories class, no matter what the repository generic type is?

Preferably, this should also be testable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `BaseRepository` class which extends `Repository` class of `typeorm` and add this method in that class. Now you need to extend your custom repositories from `BaseRepository` instead of `Repository` class of typeorm.

Example:

**BaseRepository:**

```
class BaseRepository<Entity> extends Repository<Entity> {
  async getPaginatedData(limit: number, offset: number) {
    const [data, total] = await this.findAndCount({
      take: limit,
      skip: offset,
    });

    return {
      result: data,
      count: total,
    };
  }
}
```

**UserRepository:**

```
@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User> {
  // add user related methods...
}
```

**UserService:**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserRepository) private userRepository: UserRepository,
  ) {}

getUsers() {
    // Here you have access to this method because UserRepository is extended from BaseRepository
    return this.userRepository.getPaginatedData(10, 0);
  }
}
```